# hibernate mapping file is been duplicated in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: database, hibernate, mapping, hibernate.cfg.xml

As i create a new table in my database and as i load that table from  the hibernate.reveng.xml,all the tables that is been created earlier in hibernate.cfg.xml is duplicated.I also have commented all the tables expect the last created one in hibernate.reveng.xml,again the same previous tables are duplicated in hibernate.cfg.xml file,any solutions to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicated? Are they get dropped and created again? Why you need to maintain two Hibernate config files? How you are telling Hibernate to init `Configure` object using which xml?

Comment: dupliacated in the sense ,the hbm file that are previously loaded in to the  hibernate.cfg.xml,is shown again when a new table is been mapped to the cfg,i don't need two hibernate config files,but it is automaticlly been loaded.

Comment: I think I know the problem, but can you please provided the code in both of those files so we may help you further?